# not able to forward client IP to server using HAProxy

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, iptables, haproxy

I am trying to connect my android app to server, using TCP connection.
for that, i am using HAProxy server. below is the configuration for same.

```
frontend fe-plain-cs
bind xx.xx.xx.xx:8443 transparent
default_backend be-plain-cs 

backend be-plain-cs
fullconn 50000
balance roundrobin
source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip 
server k010 xx.xx.xx.xx:8443  check inter 10m fall 1 rise 1 maxconn 25000
server k011 xx.xx.xx.xx:8443  check inter 10m fall 1 rise 1 maxconn 25000
```

if you need more info let me know.

below is my iptable rules:

```
  :PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:230]
  :INPUT ACCEPT [2:230]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:370]
  :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
  -A PREROUTING -s 10.13.0.0/16 ! -d xx.xx.xx.xx/32 -j ACCEPT
  -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination :8080
  -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination :8443
  -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 843 -j DNAT --to-destination :8843
  -A POSTROUTING -s xx.xx.xx.xx/32 -j ACCEPT
  -A POSTROUTING -s 10.13.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
  COMMIT
```

below is my sys

```
  /etc/sysctl.conf
  net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
  net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
  net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Stop your iptables service and Selinux should be disabled. 
service iptables stop
Vi etc/selinux/config
selinux=disabled